# Launch python program from another program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a stock control system for my Computer Science A level coursework. The problem I have is I do not know how to get python to launch a different python program after `Button1` is clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
top=Tk()

Button1= Button(top,text='UPDATE STOCK', width=40)
Button1.place(x=80, y=20)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, mainloop
import subprocess

def ext_python_script(event):
    subprocess.call(["python2.7", "sss.py"])   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    top = Tk()

    Button1 = Button(top, text='UPDATE STOCK', width=20, height=10)
    Button1.place(x=10, y=20)
    Button1.bind("<Button-1>", ext_python_script)

mainloop()
```

We can use bind here.

Comment: Please, add more context to your answer.

Comment: My variant is here

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from tkinter import*
import subprocess

def otherlaunch():
    subprocess.call(['python.exe', "filename.py"]) # filename.py is the file

top=Tk()

top.title('Stock Control')
top.geometry('400x200')

Button1= Button(top,text='UPDATE STOCK', width=40,command=otherlaunch)
Button1.place(x=80, y=20)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick for updating, I tested and copied the code , but it get wrongly pasted. I will be more careful next time:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `import` statement to load one python program from another, and the `command` parameter to do something on button click, like this:

```
import os 
from tkinter import*
top=Tk()

top.title('Stock Control')
top.geometry('400x200')

def run_other():
    import filename  #notice that it is not a string, and there is no '.py'

Button1= Button(top,text='UPDATE STOCK', width=40, command=run_other)
Button1.place(x=80, y=20)


mainloop()
```